# How do I return a WebDragSourceAction in webView:dragSourceActionMaskForPoint:?

Tags: swift, webview

```
    override func webView(sender: WebView!, dragSourceActionMaskForPoint point: NSPoint) -> Int {
        return WebDragSourceAction.Any
    }
```

This will result in an **error** `WebDragSourceAction is not convertible to Int`

I thought maybe I could get away with it with `WebDragSourceAction.Any.rawValue` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this issue too. What I did is looked up the Obj-C enum and copied the defined value in `return`:

```
func webView(webView: WebView!, dragSourceActionMaskForPoint point: NSPoint) -> Int
{
    return 0 // for WebDragSourceAction.None
}
```

There are the definitions of these constants:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, WebDragDestinationAction) {
    WebDragDestinationActionNone    = 0,
    WebDragDestinationActionDHTML   = 1,
    WebDragDestinationActionEdit    = 2,
    WebDragDestinationActionLoad    = 4,
    WebDragDestinationActionAny     = UINT_MAX
};

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, WebDragSourceAction) {
    WebDragSourceActionNone         = 0,
    WebDragSourceActionDHTML        = 1,
    WebDragSourceActionImage        = 2,
    WebDragSourceActionLink         = 4,
    WebDragSourceActionSelection    = 8,
    WebDragSourceActionAny          = UINT_MAX
};
```

I know that it's a workaround, but I think there's no other way to solve it.